# Use onclick in button to add a border to another div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Basically explained : click button A to add a border to card A, click button B to add a border to card B and remove border from card A etc. (these "cards" are also set up to be side scrolling so having the "highlighted card" scroll into view if it is out of view, so if you have any advice on how to do that too, I'm all ears)

This is what I have so far, but I keep getting an error that says the highlight function is not defined. I have it called on the button as onclick="highlight()"

```
function highlight() {
    var item = document.getElementById('item-id')
    var unhighlight = document.getElementsByClassName('item-class')
    unhighlight.removeClass('border');
    item.addClass('border');
}
```

Comment: Can you share your html and css if there is any ?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an HTMLCollection. You need to iterate over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simplified version that uses data attributes on the buttons and the divs to update the DOM.

1. Move your inline code to its own script.
2. Cache your elements.
3. Add an event listener to each button
4. Inside your highlight function: get the id from the button's data attribute, remove the borders from all the other divs, use the id to identify which div should now be highlighted, and then scroll it into view.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
const items = document.querySelectorAll('div');

buttons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', highlight, false));

function highlight(e) {
  const button = e.target;
  const id = button.dataset.id;
  items.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('border'));
  const div = document.querySelector(`div[data-id="${id}"]`);
  div.classList.add('border');
  div.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "end", inline: "nearest"});
}
```

```css
#container { display: flex; flex-direction: row; }
div { padding: 1em; margin: 0.5em; width: 1500px; }
.border { border: 2px solid black; }
```

```html
<button data-id="1">Click 1</button>
<button data-id="2">Click 2</button>
<button data-id="3">Click 3</button>

<div id="container">
  <div data-id="1">Hallo 1</div>
  <div data-id="2">Hallo 2</div>
  <div data-id="3">Hallo 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! The only issue I can't seem to figure out is why the page jumps down to the footer every time I press one of the buttons?

Comment: If you have a look at [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) you'll see you can pass in options to `scrollIntoView`. I've updated my answer with an example but you might need to fiddle about with them get approach the result you need.

Comment: Works like a charm. Much appreciated, Andy!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var target = $(this).data("rel");
    $(target).toggleClass("highlight");
  });
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button-a" data-rel="#card-a">A</button>
<button id="button-b" data-rel="#card-b">B</button>
<button id="button-c" data-rel="#card-c">C</button>

<div id="card-a" class="card">
  <div class="card-title">Card A</div>
</div>
<div id="card-b" class="card">
  <div class="card-title">Card B</div>
</div>
<div id="card-c" class="card">
  <div class="card-title">Card C</div>
</div>
```